# Delete duplicate columns?

Tags: r, multiple-columns, duplicates

I am collating multiple excel files into one using data frames. There are duplicate columns in the files. Is it possible to merge only the unique columns?

Here is my code:

```
library(rJava)
library (XLConnect)

data.files = list.files(pattern = "*.xls")

# Read the first file
df = readWorksheetFromFile(file=data.files[1], sheet=1, check.names=F) 

# Loop through the remaining files and merge them to the existing data frame
for (file in data.files[-1]) {
newFile = readWorksheetFromFile(file=file, sheet=1, check.names=F)
    df = merge(df, newFile, all = TRUE, check.names=F)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are much more likely to receive a helpful answer if you provide a [**minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Comment: See `t()`- transpose and `duplicated()`.

Comment: @zx8754 and what about conversion from data frame to matrix and all the undesired effects of that on eg factors (become numeric, can give wrong results) and so forth?

Comment: @JorisMeys it was just a comment/starting point as OP didn't provide reproducible data.

Comment: @zx8754 I know, but it's a bad starting point, as neither `t()` nor `duplicated()` can be of any real help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you apply `merge` correctly, there shouldn't be any duplicated columns, provided that the duplicated columns also have the exact same name in the EXCEL files. As you use `merge`, there must be at least one column in the EXCEL files that have the exact same name, and contains the values used to merge them.

So I reckon you want to check in the resulting data frame whether there are duplicate columns based on the values in each column. For this, you could use the following:

```
keepUnique <- function(x){
  combs <- combn(names(x),2)

  dups <- mapply(identical,
                 x[combs[1,]],
                 x[combs[2,]])

  drop <- combs[2,][dups]
  x[ !names(x) %in% drop ]
}
```

Which gives :

```
> mydf <- cbind(iris,iris[,3])[1:5,]
> mydf
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species iris[, 3]
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa       1.4
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa       1.4
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa       1.3
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa       1.5
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa       1.4
> keepUnique(mydf)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

You can use this after reading in a file, i.e. add the line

```
newFile <- keepUnique(newFile,df)
```

in your own code.