# R: Error: Incompatible lengths when using unnest in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large tibble ([here](https://github.com/EOneita/so-data/blob/master/test-tibble)). I created it by using [this](https://github.com/EOneita/so-data/commit/22a96e01aed6b3a6db5daf602941491747ec9260) original dataset and running the following (previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63998664/r-is-there-a-way-to-sort-messy-data-where-it-pivots-from-long-to-wide-and-as-i/64013322#64013322)):

```
#this code seemed to work
    library(tidyverse)
    df_tib <- df_full_subset %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c("name", ".value"), names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)") %>%
      select(-name) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = "01", values_from = "02", values_fn = list)
```

As can be seen in the previous post, there was a final bit of code to unnest that data. That didn't work for me so I tinkered with the tibble and found a few rubbish columns (e.g. a column of NAs), and removed those thinking that might help. However, I keep getting the same error: `"Error: Incompatible lengths: 254, 257"`. This reads to me like `dplyr` is struggling with NAs in rows 254 and 257, but I've seen other posts where this seems to be easily dealt with (like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59192648/unnest-or-unchop-dataframe-containing-lists-of-different-lengths) that used `filter`), and those solutions did not work for this data.

```
#cleaning the data
df_tib$habitat <- df_tib$habitat_
df_tib$species <- df_tib$species_
df_tib <- janitor::clean_names(df_tib)
df_tib <- df_tib %>% 
  select(-habitat_,-species_, -na)

df_tib <- df_tib %>% 
  unnest(cols = everything()) #does not work
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: @akrun sorry, I should clarify. In the un-manipulated dataset (the second link) it can be viewed in R to see the number of rows (observations). the 254 and 257 rows are filled with many NAs, which was the only thing I could think of as to why the lengths would be now incompatible, after having been manipulated into the tibble (yet still retaining that information). However, there are quite a lot of rows with NAs, so it doesn't make sense why those rows in particular would be problematic, in the original dataset.

Comment: @akrun `names_pattern` seemed to work in that top code; however, are you suggesting that an unnoticed error there could cause efforts to unnest to fail? E.g., if one of the keys was not captured by it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed you have a first column `X` in your data, that does *not* need to be included in your `pivot_longer` statement. To pivot all columns except for X, you can do `pivot_longer(cols = -X, ...)`.

I also added `drop_na` which you may have intended after `pivot_longer`. This `NA` column otherwise had missing values, objectid, and editMode.

Try this instead:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -X, names_to = c("name", ".value"), names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)") %>%
  drop_na %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "01", values_from = "02", values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest(cols = everything())
```

**Output**

```
       X bearing_degrees coordinates distance_meters habitat_ how_many_animal… observers species_ was_a_group_of_… was_the_animal_… width_of_the_ro… what_species_of… livestock
   <int> <chr>           <chr>       <chr>           <chr>    <chr>            <chr>     <chr>    <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>    
 1     1 200             N1.20701 E… 100             open_sc… 4                TW2       giraffe  group_           "alive"          single_lane      NA               NA       
 2     2 300             N1.20195 E… 20              commiph… NA               TW2 o     gerenuk  individual       "alive"          single_lane      NA               NA       
 3     3 10              N1.18823 E… 80              open_sc… NA               TW2       bird     individual       "alive"          single_lane      Ostrich          NA       
 4     4 20              N1.15642 E… 180             open_sc… 300              TW2       livesto… group_           "alive"          single_lane      NA               shoat    
 5     5 300             N1.14868 E… 30              open_sc… 7                TW2       livesto… group_           "alive"          single_lane      NA               cattle   
 6     6 70              N1.13874 E… 200             open_sc… 34               TW2       livesto… group_           "alive"          single_lane      NA               cattle   
 7     7 20              N1.11442 E… 40              disturb… 12               TW2       livesto… group_           "alive"          single_lane      NA               cattle   
 8     8 NA              N1.03003 E… NA              commiph… NA               TW2       jackal   NA               "roadkill"       single_lane      NA               NA       
 9     9 40              N1.97961 E… 50              mixed_s… null             TW2       gerenuk  individual       "alive,\n    wh… NA               NA               null     
10    10 20              N0.85822 E… 20              dense_s… 53               TW2       baboon   group_           "alive"          single_lane      NA               NA       
# … with 251 more rows, and 5 more variables: approximate_age_of_individual <chr>, approximate_number_of_days_sinc <chr>, sex_of_animal <chr>, generated_note_survey <chr>,
#   `_date` <chr>
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you @Ben! My stumbling block was trying to get rid of the NAs upstream (in the original dataset) and just before the unnest command... I should have thought to do it after pivot_longer!